# Is it a good idea to extend a grails domain object?

Tags: grails, extending, domain-object

I need similar object as grails domain object which does not need persisting. In order that I do not have to make changes in 2 places for any field changes, is it a good idea to extend the domain class so that I can get the benefits of single set of fields. Although all related objects and collections will need to be redone.

Comment: Domain class contains a lot of other things also. So instead of extending the domain class, put your fields in a groovy file and extend that in your domain class.

Comment: also consider using a `trait` to not lock yourself into some inheritance hell

Answer (score 2):

@cfrick is spot on. A Groovy trait is a very good way to go. You can get a full example [here](https://bitbucket.org/erosa/inheritance-example) (bad name for the project, I know). Here's a quick example:

```
// MyTrain.groovy: Put this in src/main/groovy/my/package
package my.package

trait MyTrait {
    Integer number
    String something
}

// MyDomainClass.groovy: This goes with the other domain classes.
package my.package

class MyDomainClass implements MyTrait {
    /*  
     * number and something properties are available here.
     * They become table columns.
     */  

    static constraints {
        /*  
         * And you can place constraints on them,
         * as it they had been declared in this class.
         */  
    }   
}
```

Comment: Dead link / non-existing bitbucket repo. But great example! Thanks!